# LTE EPC Synchronization between redundant components

Tags: network-core, lte

I am investigating resiliency in LTE Evolved Packet Core.

Each EPC components has information storage as defined for each user in 3GPP TS 23.40 (Ch 5.7).

In case of failure this info needs to be sent to redundant component (synchronization).

I want to know how much is the size of the info storage for each user. Then I can made deductions about the synchronization load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be calculated based on the respective fields in the respective information storage of HSS/MME/SGW/PGW as mentioned in section 5.7.

One tip is that the following 3GPP specs can be referred for respective IE in information storage to determine the sizes.

1. S1AP IEs - 36.413
2. RRC  IEs - 36.331
3. GTP-C IEs - 29.274
4. GTP-U IEs - 29.281
5. NAS IEs - 24.301